# Несколько языков в приложении

Tags: java, android, multilanguage

Продолжаю работать над своим трёх-фрагментным калькулятором, можно сказать я уже на финишной прямой.

Так вот, я добавил в него 2 языка: английский и русский с помощью string ресурсов, и у меня есть несколько вопросов.

1. Язык в приложении зависит от языка устройства, т.е. если я в настройках телефона поставлю язык по умолчанию английский, то и моё приложение будет на английском. Как сделать переключение языка по кнопке прямо в приложении?
2. В некоторых случаях я использовал ImageView для отображения формул по случаю, но в одной из формул есть слово "ИЛИ", которое сильно бросается в глаза, когда приложение на английском. Можно ли выводить разные изображения в ImageView в зависимости от языка в приложении?

Comment: 1. Зачем? Если у юзера всё остальное на инглише - на кой он будет включать русский в вашем калькуляторе? 2. Да, можно - так же как и строки, сделать альтернативные картинки и положить в папки с языковым квалификатором (ака `../drawable-hdpi-ru/or.png`)

Comment: Кстати, хороший вопрос, но почему бы и нет? Добавить переключатель в настройках, чисто для практики)

Comment: Можно пожалуйста поподробнее насчёт картинок?

Comment: @Art Не нужно писать над чем вы работаете, ваш прогресс и т.п. Задавайте конкретный вопрос, это не блог.

Comment: Понял, учту. Просто у меня ряд вопросов, которые взаимосвязаны между собой, и возможно будет легче их понять, зная на какой я стадии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, null);
getApplicationContext().resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, null);
```

для переключения языка вручную надо использовать следующий код.
НО!
он должен идти ДО метода `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: Да, решение работает. Но я решил всё-таки оставить как было, чтобы язык переключался автоматически. Настройки будут для темы, спасибо за ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Насчёт второго вопроса: нужно условием проверить язык, и если он русский, то вывести одно изображение, если нет, то другое.

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: Нет, это именно решение вопроса

Comment: Это делается не так - делаем вторую картинку с тем же названием и кладём её в папку с таким же именем, что и у оригинала, только с суффиксом локали. То есть если есть картинка `/drawable-hdpi/or.png`, создаём локализованную и кладём в `/drawable-ru-hdpi/or.png` 
 и так для каждого дополнительного языка. В коде вы будете использовать один `id`, а нужная версия картинки загружаться автоматом. Тут офф. гайд (как всегда не особо понятный): https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources